# Breaking Liskov substitution principle by adding more logic

Tags: java, oop, liskov-substitution-principle

I have a class: User and Customer. User has basic getters, setters for a name, email, and stuff which Customer needs as well but Customer has methods like `getOrders()` which other subclasses of a class User does not have, let's say ProjectManager. Does that mean Customer should not extend User and have its own first_name, last_name, email... attributes?

Or is it okay for the class Customer to extend the class User and extend the logic by methods for orders and customer-related methods?

Answer (score 1):

> Or is it okay for the class Customer to extend the class User

Yes, that is exactly how it should go. The pricinple tells us that Customer (or any other subclass of User) must be able to be used wherever a User is expected. The same doesn't need to be able to happen the other way around, and the subclasses don't have to be substitutable with each others.

Comment: The question is "Does that mean Customer should not extend User ... Or is it okay for the class Customer to extend the class User ... ?" Briefly, "to extend or not to extend". You answered "Yes". Yes to what option? I'd suggest you improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The question you should ask is from an OO-perspective, does it make sense? 
Is a customer a user, or are customers sometimes not users? Or are all users customers?
First consider your object model from a logical point. Do not try to artificially be smart by laying connections which logically aren't there.

I don't know the domain in which you are using this. A user may be something which uses your product, a customer may be the entity buying products from you and supplying it to users. If that's the case, there is no IS-A relation, only a HAS-A relation. So they should not inherit.
The fact that quite a number of fields are then duplicated is 'fine'. You could solve that by having a `Person` class, from which both inherit